# Cannot deploy website made by Blogdown in Github Pages

Tags: r, github-pages, netlify, bookdown, blogdown

I want to deploy a [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)-based website made using the [blogdown](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blogdown/index.html) package in Github Pages, while keeping the R source code of the website in the same repository. This should be achievable by generating the website files in the `docs` directory in the Github repository, and then pointing Github Pages to the `docs` folder in the `main` branch. However, I could not make it work.

Here, I describe a simple blogdown site to demonstrate the problem. The directory is created using Rstudio with the options as shown in the following picture.

[image: Initial options for generating website using blogdown and Hugo]

I have edited the `config.toml` file, in particular to set the `publishDir` as `docs` and add a logo to the website. The content of the edited `config.toml` file is given below.

```
baseurl = "/"
publishDir = "docs"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "Blogdown website in Github Pages"
theme = "hugo-lithium"
googleAnalytics = ""
disqusShortname = ""
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$"]

[permalinks]
    post = "/:year/:month/:day/:slug/"

[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/about/"

[params]
    description = "Demonstrating problem in deploying a blogdown website in Github Pages."

    # options for highlight.js (version, additional languages, and theme)
    highlightjsVersion = "9.12.0"
    highlightjsCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml"]
    highlightjsTheme = "github"

    MathJaxCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    MathJaxVersion = "2.7.5"

    [params.logo]
    url = "logo.png"
    width = 50
    height = 50
    alt = "Logo"
```

I have also edited the value of the `publish` parameter in the `netlify.toml` file to `docs`. I have done this to have the option to deploy the website using Netlify apart from Github Pages. The content of the edited `netlify.toml` file is:

```
[build]
command = 'hugo'
publish = 'docs'
[build.environment]
HUGO_VERSION = '0.89.4'


[context]
[context.branch-deploy]
command = 'hugo -F -b $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL'

[context.deploy-preview]
command = 'hugo -F -b $DEPLOY_PRIME_URL'

[context.production]
[context.production.environment]
HUGO_ENV = 'production'
```

Content of the website is added in the `content` folder, which includes an `about.md` file and a sample post `2021-12-09-sample-post.Rmd`. The structure of the `content` folder is:

```
content
   |-- about.md
   |-- post
        |-- 2021-12-09-sample-post.Rmd
```

The logo is added by placing the file `logo.png` in the `static\images` directory. The source code of this example can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/deploymentproblem-source). The local build in RStudio runs perfectly well. The files after building the website locally are uploaded [here](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/deploymentproblem). I have placed the `.nojekyll` file in both the `main` directory and the `docs` folder to prevent Github Pages from using Jekyll.

However, the generated Github Pages site [does not work](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/). But [it works perfectly in Netlify](https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/).

I have also tried changing the value of the `baseurl` argument in the file `config.toml` to point to the Github hosting directory. The website is generated perfectly in RStudio through blogdown. The source code as well as the generated website files are uploaded [here](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/deploymentproblem_baseurlchanged). But now, [neither Github Pages](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem_baseurlchanged/) [nor Netlify](https://deploymentproblembaseurlchanged.netlify.app/) correctly deploys the website.

I wish to be able to deploy the website in both Github Pages and Netlify, just like which can be done for a website generated using the `bookdown` package in R. If that is not possible at all, I wish to be able to deploy the website in Github Pages at least. I wonder what mistakes I am making in the website code or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: set `relativeURLs = true` in `config.toml`, so that your pages use relative URLs (but this is really up to the theme's support for relative URLs; the `hugo-lithium` theme should be good).

Longer answer:

Your Github Pages URL https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/ contains a subpath `deploymentproblem/`, whereas your Netlify URL does not: https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/. If you don't use relative URLs, resources won't be correctly loaded on one of these two sites, e.g., `/images/logo.png` on https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/ means https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/images/logo.png, which is wrong (should have been https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/images/logo.png instead), but it is correct on the Netlify site: https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/images/logo.png. Absolute/relative URLs are tricky but extremely important to understand. You may read the last part of the [Appendix B.1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/html.html) of the **blogdown** book.

Another solution is to specify different `baseURL`s for different sites. For example, you may configure

```
baseURL: "https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/"
```

in `config.toml`, but override it in `netlify.toml`:

```
[build]
command = 'hugo -b https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still did not solve the problem. Following your advice, I have added `relativeURLs = true` in `config.toml`, generated the website files afresh using blogdown in RStudio, uploaded those files in Github after placing `.nojekyll` in both `main` directory and `docs` folder and then re-generated the Github Pages site. But still, the [Github Pages site](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/) is not displayed correctly: it does not show the link of the post, whereas the [Netlify site, deployed afresh](https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/), works perfectly.

Comment: Incidentally, the same error of not showing the post link occurs in the Github Pages site when I use `baseURL: "https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/"` in `config.toml`. Your second suggested solution also does not work in the Github Pages site as I have said above: the link of the post is not shown. Also, I would prefer to not add the baseURL in order to not include anything specific for Github in the source code, which should make the website easily portable. I shall really appreciate it if you could please say what I should do to make the website work correctly!

Comment: How did you rebuild the site for Github Pages? You should run `blogdown::build_site()`, or equivalently, `Ctrl/Command + Shift + B` in RStudio. `blogdown::serve_site()` is not enough. That's one of the reasons why I personally don't recommend Github Pages---you have to manually build your site every single time.

Comment: I have run `blogdown::build_site()`, but still the same problem persists. To explain the problem, I have downloaded the source code from [here](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/deploymentproblem-source), opened the project in RStudio in my computer run the commands `blogdown::build_site()` and `blogdown::serve_site()` (see [screenshot](https://imgur.com/p9LCK9V)), and then uploaded all the files including the `docs` folder to [here](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/deploymentproblem/) after placing the `.nojekyll` file in both the `main` directory and the `docs` folder. (continued..)

Comment: (continued from above) Then, re-generated the Github Pages site [here](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/deploymentproblem/), but still, the link of the post is not displayed. I have redeployed the site using Netlify, and everything works file. I just cannot understand what mistake I am making, and shall very much appreciate it if you please point that out!

Comment: The link of the Netlify site is [this](https://deploymentproblem.netlify.app/), where the link of the post is displayed correctly.

Comment: I have read your post about why you prefer Netlify over Github Pages, and I can see from my own experience the problem with Github Pages. However, I wish to have the Github Pages sites for my Github repos, and I have seen bookdown works perfectly here with both Github Pages and Netlify. I wish to have the same with blogdown, without having any Github specific configuration in my website files, if that is possible. I have read a good part of your blogdown book, and several other related posts, but just could not find the mistake I am making!