# Is it possible to deploy a blogdown website containing Rmd post in Github Pages using relative url?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am trying to deploy a blogdown website in Github Pages using relative url's, but to no avail. To demonstrate the problem, I have used here the example site provided with the theme hugo-lithium in blogdown (Image 1). I have added the lines `relativeURLs: true` and `publishDir: "docs"` in the `config.yaml` file (Image 2), and edited the `publish` argument in the `netlify.toml` file to `publish = 'docs'` (Image 3).

[image: Using the example site with sample blog posts in hugo-lithium]

<sup>*Image 1.*</sup>

[image: Adding relative url and changing publish directory in config.yaml file]

<sup>*Image 2.*</sup>

[image: Setting publish directory to 'docs' in netlify.toml file]

<sup>*Image 3.*</sup>

Next, I have run the commands `blogdown::build_site()` and `blogdown::serve_site()` (Image 4). The example site is correctly generated locally, with all the posts visible. I have then uploaded the [project directory to Github](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem) and added the file `.nojekyll` in the ['docs' folder](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem/tree/main/docs). After uploading the site files, I have generated the [Github Pages website](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/blogdown-problem/) from the ['docs' folder](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem/tree/main/docs), and also the [netlify website](https://blogdown-problem.netlify.app/).

[image: Executing blogdown::build_site() and blogdown::serve_site()]

<sup>*Image 4.*</sup>

Unfortunately, while the [netlify website](https://blogdown-problem.netlify.app/) displays all the posts correctly, the [Github Pages website](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/blogdown-problem/) does not display [one of the posts](https://blogdown-problem.netlify.app/2020/12/01/hello-r-markdown/), which is the only post written in R markdown (Rmd file).

On further inspection, I have found that the [`index.html` file](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem/blob/main/docs/index.html) in the aforementioned 'docs' folder does not contain any link to the Rmd post, and its corresponding folder (should have been named '2020') is absent from the ['docs' folder](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem/tree/main/docs). This should be the reason the Github Pages website does not display the link to the missing post. I have downloaded the generated files for the [netlify website](https://blogdown-problem.netlify.app/) from Netlify, which correctly contain the folder named '2020' and the link to the corresponding post in the `index.html` file. I have uploaded these netlify files in another [Github repository](https://github.com/joydeepchowdhury/blogdown-problem-netlify-deploy), and have generated the corresponding [Github Pages website](https://joydeepchowdhury.github.io/blogdown-problem-netlify-deploy/), which now, unsurprisingly, works perfectly.

I wish to know what I need to do to make a blogdown website containing an Rmd post deployed properly in Github Pages, using relative urls. I wonder why the corresponding directories and the links to Rmd posts are not created even after running `blogdown::build_site()` and `blogdown::serve_site()`, whereas the site is correctly displayed locally, and Netlify displays the site correctly by successfully creating those missing directories and links in the `index.html` file. Or, whether it is a bug in the blogdown package, and such a simple website, which is also provided as an example with the blogdown package, cannot in fact be deployed in Github Pages.

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294804/cannot-deploy-website-made-by-blogdown-in-github-pages), whose [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295584/8925012), unfortunately, does not work.